# How does energy and speed affect sub-atomic particles (protons, neutrons, electrons) in an electric field

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

[image]

(Source: https://gyazo.com/a4d5beed3272a7ca793dd8e2f7e8be3c)

I am having trouble understanding the problem above. Why does it matter if the particles are held at constant energy or speed? How does energy and speed even affect sub-atomic particles. Why do the different constants produce different diagrams?

Comment: Such a question belongs rather to the physics SE site.

Comment: It literally came from a chemistry website

Comment: Surrey, but it is a topic of physics. I am writing an answer.

Comment: ..but note that:  We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. 
Basically any question with the wording your question has is considered homework; it needn't be literally one. Self-study questions, puzzles etc. also count as homework. 

Don't worry, they're not banned. But, we require a minimal effort. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

See [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs to physics SE

Comment: Because different masses and different charges lead to differences in how the particles interact with electric fields.

Answer (score 1):

The energy and speed  do not affect particles themselves, but their interactions with other diatomic objects.

And, of course, they affect their kinematics in electromagnetic field.

Kinetic energy of a particle is

$$E_\mathrm{k}=\frac 12 \cdot m \cdot v^2$$

The force on a charged particle in an electrostatic field of the strength $E$ is

$$\vec F=q\cdot \vec E$$

The perpendicular acceleration is

$$\vec a=\vec F/m=\frac{q\cdot \vec E}{m}$$

For the length of the path between the electrodes $L$, the time of flight is

$$t=\frac Lv=L \cdot \sqrt{ \left( \frac {m}{2\cdot E_\mathrm{k}}\right)}$$

The perpendicular deviation due the  acceleration in the field is

$$\begin{align}
\vec L_\mathrm{p}&=\frac 12 \cdot a  \cdot t^2 \\
&= \frac 12 \cdot \frac{q\cdot \vec E}{m} \cdot  \left( \frac {L^2\cdot m}{2\cdot E_\mathrm{k}}\right) \\
&= \frac 14 \cdot q \cdot  L^2 \cdot \frac{\vec E}{E_\mathrm{k}}\\
\end{align}$$

One can see the **bending with the equal kinetic energy is mass independent.**

The scenario with the **equal speed** is a different story, as the **perpendicular acceleration has the reciprocal proportionality to the mass**, so the path of the much lighter electron is bent much more.